# How to install database with Spring MVC

Tags: database, spring, spring-mvc

I've got a Spring MVC project which I've received from another developer. I usually find .sql files there to initialize the DB, but this code doesn't seem to have anything like that. I doesn't use Roo or any tools that I know that can do database initialization.

I've been using Python/Django for a while now, so I guess my question is: is there something I could use with Spring MVC like Django's "manage.py syncdb" to initialize the database based on the code? Maybe a build task or a script or anything other than reverse engineering the code and figuring out what tables should go to the DB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### The easiest solution

- If you can still talk to that "other developer" => **just ask**

If the above does not work...

You have to understand what persistence mechanism / technology this project is based on. Here are few examples:

### It Is Based On Hibernate

Just search for the word `hibernate` in all the files. Do you see anything? Take a look at project's dependencies, does it have any hibernate jars? etc..

If it is indeed Hibernate, you can generate your schema based on your domain objects (close to Django's "manage.py syncdb"), by adding the following Hibernate property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
```

to a sessionFactory bean. It would look similar to [this](https://github.com/anatoly-polinsky/money-making-project/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/conf/spring/persistence-spring-config.xml) configuration. Or if you have "persistence.xml" file instead, add this property ( under Hibernate properties ) there. You'd have to "run" the project in order to create this schema.

### It Is Based On Spring JDBC ([Template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html))

Again, search for it.

In this case you will have to write some SQL ( think about it as Rails migration, but in SQL :) ). Once you do that, you can use *in memory* DB, such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) (by default it uses HSQLDB), to actually achieve the same effect as with "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto":

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Here is more about [Embedded DB Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-embedded-database-support)

### It Is Based On Magic

Nothing to search for really in this case (well, maybe for `DAO` or `Repository`), but the simplest approach would be to just take a single service, and follow the white rabbit:

```
service.rememberThePlace( place ) { placeDao.save( place ) }
```

Now look at the Dao.. does it have any `Hibernate` imports? What about `...JdbcTemplate`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Not unless it uses a DB/ORM mechanism that can be interrogated or read from config files.

There's no way to magically create a DB without knowing what the DB model is. If it uses an ORM, there will likely be XML mapping files, or annotated classes, that describe the database structure (or at least some of it). Most ORMs have some way of taking that configuration and turning it into DDL.

If it's not using an ORM, like if it's using Spring JDBC, you either need the DB structure given to you, or you get to reverse-engineer it from the SQL contained in the code (or config, depends).

If it's using an OODB then it depends.

Comment: It's supposed to be using MySQL and I can't find any reference to Hibernate or similar things. So I assume the only way is to get the SQL scripts somehow from the developer or spend hours to figure out the db schema. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @toocsh If you add the app's libraries to the question someone might be able to figure out if it's using anything else; some ORM/OODBs are completely reflective.